# C# wait DLL async method to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, task

I have a DLL which has `public Task<>` method which returns `return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...)`. I am calling it within a program and I want the program to wait for the execution of the task to finish before it continues doing other things. I've added `Thread.Sleep(6000)` to the DLL to simulate longer execution.

When I'm calling it like this

```
var invokedTask = myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams);
```

It just continues with execution (as expected). But then I tried this:

```
var invokedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams));
invokedTask.Wait();
```

And it doesn't work. How can I make it wait from outside of DLL?

Comment: In your second example, you're creating a *new* `Task`. The only job you're giving that task is to run the `myMethod` function and *ignore* the task that it returns. So, of course, that `Task` doesn't take long to complete. Why don't you just `Wait` `invokedTask` in your first example?

Comment: Tried it already, but `invokedTask` is not of `Task` type, but `object`

Comment: But it really is a `Task`. All you need is a cast - not mucking about creating more `Task`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Wait` for the task that is being returned - don't spin up *another* `Task` just to call the original method:

```
var invokedTask = (Task)myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams);
invokedTask.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the calling method must have the async keyword in the definition:

```
async void (or Task) MyCaller()
{
  await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams));

}
```

void or Task depends on which context you are in.

Answer (score 0):

When you `wait()` a `Task.Factory.StartNew()` the result is a `Task`
Therefore you have to call `wait()` two times or you can use `await` operator.

Therefore you can do the following.

```
var invokedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams));
var result=await await invokedTask;
```

Or you can do the following

```
var invokedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams));
invokedTask.Wait();
var resultTask=invokedTask.Result;
resultTask.Wait();
var result=resultTask.Result;
```

However from the question you have posted, it looks like your  `myMethod.Invoke()` returns `Task.Factor.StartNew()` therefore I would like you to try

```
var result =await await myMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(myClass), myParams);
```

However it is a bad practice to use Wait() and then Result() as it block the current thread.
Therefore I would like you to use await.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help:

```
public class MagicClass
{
    private int magicBaseValue;

    public MagicClass()
    {
        magicBaseValue = 9;
    }

    public Task<int> ItsMagic(int preMagic)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => preMagic * magicBaseValue);
    }
}

public class TestMethodInfo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100
        Type magicType = typeof(MagicClass);
        MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
        var magicValue = ((Task<int>)(magicMethod.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MagicClass)), new object[] { 100 }))).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("MethodInfo.Invoke() Example\n");
        Console.WriteLine("MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: {0}", magicValue.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can cast your Invoke as a Task<> and then get the Result.  This will wait until the method is done executing.